# SUBQUERY de comparação MySQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz uma query para selecionar todos os registros de usuário de uma tabela, porém inseri um filtro onde o admin seleciona o estado e filtra apenas os registros de usuários do UF selecionado, mas está dando erro no retorno.

```
<?php
if( !isset( $_GET['uf'] ) ) {

## Assim funciona corretamente, retorna todos registros de todos usuários
$sql = "SELECT r.* FROM `registros` FROM `registros` r WHERE r.`registro` = 'A' ORDER BY r.`registros_data_cad` DESC";

} else if ( isset( $_GET['uf'] ) ) { 

## Assim seleciona apenas registros de um UF, ex: AC
$where_clause = "AND ( SELECT u.`user_uf` FROM `user` u WHERE u.`user_uf` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli, $_REQUEST['uf'] ) . "' )";

$sql = "SELECT r.* FROM `registros` FROM `registros` r " WHERE r.`registro` = 'A' " . $where_clause . " ORDER BY r.`registros_data_cad` DESC";

}
?>
```

Tentei desse modo mas dá erro, poderiam me dar um help aqui?

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in /home/atc2018/public_html/saldo.php on line 106;

Colando no phpmyadmin dá erro #1054, consultei e é coluna inexistente, porém a coluna existe.

Comment: Qual seria o erro? Faltou informar isso apenas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o problema está nos pontos "." da sua *query*.

Experimente alterar a sua variável `$sql` da seguinte forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT r.* FROM `registros` r WHERE r.`registro` = 'A' ". $where_clause ." ORDER BY r.`registros_data_cad` DESC";
```

Comment: Desculpe, o erro do ponto foi ao inserir aqui, mas o ponto existe. Complementei a pergunta.

Comment: @AngeloJ Leia essa resposta com mais atenção... Você editou sua pergunta, mas está resposta ainda corrige seu problema!

Comment: isso, verdade, não havia reparado a alteração além dos pontos, obrigado!

Comment: Não deu mais erro, mas retorna 0 registros. Mas na tabela do usuário o campo UF é AC e nos registros tem usuários de UF do Acre.

Comment: Aí já terá que validar a sua _query_ SQL.